# partclone, ntfsclone, partimage, G4L: compatibility and feature set

Tags: linux, backup, ntfs, clonezilla, ntfs-3g

I have a very specific use case for which I am looking into Linux-based backup solutions that can be used to back up (not necessarily clone) and restore a Windows system (XP through 8.1 must be supported).

The idea is to use PXE (e.g. through [DRBL](http://drbl.sourceforge.net/)) in order to boot an array of machines which is used for test runs. These test runs are largely automated, but every once in a while a machine will lock up and that's taken care of by having a network-controlled power supply.

The options I have been looking at are:

- [Clonezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/), based on [partclone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partclone/)
- ntfsclone, part of [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) ([`ntfsclone(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsclone))
- [partimage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partimage/)
- [G4L](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/)

Now, *I am not* asking for a comparison of these programs. But what I am interested in is the compatibility between each other (obviously Clonezilla and partclone will be compatible) with respect to the image format.

Another aspect is how the respective solutions can be automated out of the box. Of course I can also go and write a shell script, but even for that I'll need a program that can be used from the command line.

**So my questions:**

- How compatible are the image formats created by the four mentioned programs (partclone, ntfsclone, partimage or G4L)?
- Which of them can be automated out of the box?
- Which of them have *no* program that I can control from the command line?

Comment: Side-note: partimage is the least desirable, so an answer can skip that one.

Comment: (1) Why are you looking for interoperability between various backup programs? Why don't you just use **one** backup program? Clonezilla is pretty efficient. (2) Do you need a live backup (to backup files while the system is actively working)?

Comment: @medigeek: easy, because the different programs offer different options, although they overlap in large parts.

Answer (score 0):

### Clonezilla

You're looking for a way to create an unattended backup, i.e. a less interactive way that does not include the command line. I've never tried an unattended setup/configuration, but **Clonezilla** has what you need, but you need to configure it in a "nerdy way" (i.e. you need to know how to use the program through command line/terminal):

- http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting/00-modify-syslinux-isolinux-cfg.doc#00-modify-syslinux-isolinux-cfg.doc
- http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting/01-preseed-options.doc#01-preseed-options.doc
- http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=clonezilla-live/doc/99_Misc/00_live-boot-parameters.doc (find available boot parameters and which config file you need to prepare)

If you setup the **kernel boot parameters** properly on "Clonezilla live" you can get a fully automated backup solution, tailored to your needs.

### Deja-dup and duplicity

On the other hand, if you're looking for a GUI to make backups of files (not images), is deja-dup (gui) and duplicity (command line) is your definite answer.

You can boot from a Ubuntu Live CD (or a Live USB if you want to preserve changes) or you can install Ubuntu on every PC and use it as an "OS" that serves only for backups.

duplicity works through rsync. It uses incremental and full backups every now and then in order to avoid long incremental chains.

Here's a review: http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/

> From the Storage pane, you can customize where Déjà Dup puts your
>   backups. If you back up to Ubuntu One (and have set up Ubuntu One on
>   your computer) your backup will be accessible from any computer, so
>   you can easily restore your personal data on any Linux system. You can
>   also back up to other types of remote servers, including **FTP, SSH,
>   WebDAV, and Windows shared folders**. Déjà Dup’s encryption protects
>   your data with a password you provide.
>
> The local folder option can back up your data to an external drive or
>   other local storage device. Putting the backup on the same drive as
>   the original files is a bad idea — you’ll lose both the backup and the
>   originals if the drive fails.

Comment: Not just backup, the restore process ought to be automated as well in this case :)

Comment: **Clonezilla** asks you to create a restore CD/DVD/USB: http://clonezilla-sysresccd.hellug.gr/restore.html // http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/clonezilla -- You will have to become accustomed to the command line and syslinux customization in order to do what you want though.

Comment: Deja-dup also has a restore function: http://www.linuxstall.com/backup-ubuntu-11-10-using-deja-dup-backup-tool/ (scroll down) -- It asks the user where's the backup and where to restore it to.